# Circle Parametric equation in $3D$ space?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, circles, rotations

What are the parametric equations of a circle in $x z$ plane with a rotation a round $z$-axis ? so if

> $x = r * \cos(\theta)$
>
> $z = r * \sin(\theta)$

what should $y =$ ??

Comment: If I'm understanding your description properly, it sounds like $y=0$, so your parametric representation is: $(r\cos\theta,0,r\sin\theta)$

Comment: yes, when y = 0 the circle is in xz plane, now I want to rotate it around z-axis ?

Comment: I see... it sounds as if you'll need one parameter, $\theta$, to trace out your circle, and another parameter, $t$, to make it rotate?

Comment: You should start from the parametrization of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then fix the polar angle to the desired value

Comment: G Tony, --> thats exactly what i am trying to do, so $theta$ for the circle and t for the tilt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle

$$
p = (r\cos(t),0,r\sin(t))
$$

rotated around the $z$ axis is built with the rotation matrix

$$
R(\theta) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) & 0 \\
 \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In new coordinates reads

$$
p\cdot R(\theta) = (r \cos (\theta ) \cos (t),-r \sin (\theta ) \cos (t),r \sin (t))
$$

Attached a rotated circle (red) by $\frac{\pi}{3}$

[image]

Comment: great visuals, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

$HINT:$

You can see geometrically that :

any point $P(x,0,z)$ in the $XY-plane$,

if rotated about the $Z-axis$ by an angle $α$ with the $XZ- plane$ changes to :

$(x-x.cosα, x.sinα, z)$.

so if your original coordinates are:

$(r.cosθ,0,r.sinθ)$,(in the $XZ$-plane)

they will change to:

$x=r.cosθ-r.cosθ.cosα$

$y=r.cosθ.sinα$

$z=r.sinθ$

Comment: thanks a lot, works :) could you tell where is the source of such equations ?

Comment: you can take the coordinates of a point (x,0,z). Rotate it about z-axis in a rough diagram by an angle α, and use trignometric ratios to find the final directed distances from x,y,z axis. Hence finding the final coordinates.(sorry i cannot attach a photo yet)

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats really helpful